# Magento 2 - How to add Imprint and other links to copyright in footer

Tags: magento2, template

I want to add some new links in the copyright row of the Luma theme footer.

What's the best practice to do that and how can I do it?

I've the following ideas, but I don't know if there are other solutions.

1. Copy the copyright.phtml of the Luma theme to a custom theme and extend it with html.
2. Create a new template (phtml file) and paste it into the page via default.xml?

Thanks.

Marco

Answer (score 2):

In admin go to

> Content -> Configuration

Then click "edit" and scroll to the "Footer" section

Answer (score 1):

One possible area is to add your link/html-code by navigating to `Stores->Configuration->General->Design->Footer->Copyright` along with your copyright text.